# Gitlab: How to fetch latest update to my local branch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have cloned a gitlab repository on my local system and created a local branch called "feature/b1" and made some changes on this local branch. Now while reviewing, my colleague has made some updates on my local branch (feature/b1) on top of my changes from his system. Now how can I get the latest local branch on my system means whatever changes I made + also changes made by my colleague.

Is git fetch command will do

Comment: First do a `git stash` and `git pull rebase`. once that is done add your changes by doing `git stash pop`